# How to group in mongo from ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, syntax, group-by, database

I'm trying to group by 2 fields in my mongo collection from ruby. I've got it working from within the mongo client however can't get the ruby syntax right.

My command on the mongo client is

```
db.truckroutes.group({key: { "route" : 0, "assetId" : "" }, reduce: function (curr, result) {}, initial: {} })
```

Could anyone give me any ideas what the ruby syntax would be like to perform this command?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, managed to fix this after spending a while experimenting.

```
trucks = @mongoCollection.group( ["route", "assetId"], { }, { }, "function() {}")
```